# How to get html text input value and output in swift

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, xcode

When a user inputs text to a html input is it possible to read and collect that value through a webkit view in swift? For example the html in the Webkit view is this:

```
<input id="username" type="text">
```

I want to be able to collect what ever text they put in that and store it as a string. I tried this swift code from a stack post:

```
var id:String = IBwebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('myId').value")!
        println(id)
```

However it didn't work. I'm VERY VERY new to swift and Ios development so any help would be awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change  "('myId')" to "('username')".

Inside of `document.getElementById()` should be the **id name** you assigned to the HTML tag.

In your case the id name of your tag, `<input id="username" type="text">` is **username**

**Final result:**

```
var id:String = IBwebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('username').value")!
```